# Running in emulator is complete but In tablet there is an error that no such table while compiling select * from table

Tags: android, sqlite, android-emulator

I am new to creating apps in android(eclipse). Now I am developing an account tracker application but there is a problem occurring when I open my app on my tablet but in the android emulator it works properly.

The error is: no **such table when compiling select * from table name.**

Please tell me why is this error only occurring on the tablet but not in the eclipse emulator.

Here is my code:

```
try
{
  db= SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("sdcard/tracker.db",null,SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
            Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery("select * from add_transaction",null);  
            int theTotal= c1.getCount();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Total: "+ theTotal, 1).show();
            String[] args= {"acc_no","trans_type","amount"};

  int acc_no_transCol= c1.getColumnIndex("acc_no");
  int trans_typeCol= c1.getColumnIndex("trans_type");
  int amountCol = c1.getColumnIndex("amount");
  TextView t1=null;


  while(c1.moveToNext()) {
    t1=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    t1.setText("textbox");
    t1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff009999"));
    l1.addView(t1);

    args[0] = Integer.toString((c1.getInt(acc_no_transCol)));
    args[1] = c1.getString(trans_typeCol);
    args[2] = Float.toString((c1.getFloat(amountCol)));

    t1.append("\nAccount Number: "+ args[0]+"\nTransaction Type: "+args[1]+"\nCurrent Balance: "+args[2]+"\n");
    //advance to the next record (first rec. if necessary)
  }
}  
catch (Exception e)
{
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(), 
                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: can you explain i mean which table r u using? u created using sqlite?

Comment: yes m created table using SQlite..

Comment: post your helper class code which creates the database...and yes if you are direct running app in tab for searching it won't we need to create database first

Comment: i don't create helper class..N my confusion is there that in emulator my app is running successfully but in tablet y it not??? basically running in emul is final step to test app na....

Comment: did you enter any account number, transcation number in your app?? or direct fetching it??

Comment: yes first i've insert the acc_no and other related data in add_transaction table..and then i m fetching it from add_transaction table to recent_transaction form.

Comment: you enter these details also in tab and then tried to search??

Comment: inserting and fetching operation are successfully run in emulator..it works fine..

Comment: Dont hardcode "sdcard" use Environment and also before opening database check whether the file is available through code.

Comment: yes i've done it manytimes..In tab record is inserted successfully too..problem is occurring while displaying it.

Comment: yes i've check it..no problem at all in unavailability of file...

Comment: is it necessary to create helper class  for database? we do not manually create db on main activity?

Comment: Have u tried un-installing and then installing the app again on tab.
coz the tab may have earlier version of database installed for it.. whether there are chances that you may have added this table later on in development cycle of the app.

It happens when you prefer to install already created database file from the assets folder... and that actually is installed once in the apps life cycle that too when for the frst time the app was launched.. later on doesn't matter how many times he app is overwrought database structure remains the same

Comment: yaa i've tried it manytimes..but it's not working...do we have to copy a database in assets folder??? i've tried that also but still not working....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.account;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
//import android.view.View;
//import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.*;

public class recent_trans extends Activity {
    TextView curr_user;
    //TextView data;
    Button logout, cancel;
    ImageButton home;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    String[] name;
    LinearLayout l1;



     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.recent_trans);

            db = openOrCreateDatabase("tracker.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Database Is Created Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


           l1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1); 
           curr_user = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblcurrent_user);
           //data = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
           home = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.img_btn_home);
           logout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnlogout);
           cancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btncancel);

            Intent myLocalIntent= getIntent();
            Bundle myBundle= myLocalIntent.getExtras();
            String v1 = myBundle.getString("uname");
            curr_user.setText(v1);

            db= SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("sdcard/tracker.db",null,SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
            **try
            {

                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE add_transaction(acc_no INTEGER,trans_type TEXT,date DATE,amount FLOAT,cheque_no INTEGER,party_name VARCHAR(20),detail VARCHAR(200));");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Table Is Created Successfully....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Table Is Already Exists.....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }**

     try
     {


            //db = openOrCreateDatabase("tracker.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);


            Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery("select * from add_transaction",null);  
            int theTotal= c1.getCount();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Total: "+ theTotal, 1).show();
            String[] args= {"acc_no","trans_type","amount"};
            //Cursor c1= db.rawQuery(mySQL,null);

            int acc_no_transCol= c1.getColumnIndex("acc_no");
            int trans_typeCol= c1.getColumnIndex("trans_type");
            int amountCol = c1.getColumnIndex("amount");
            TextView t1=null;


            while(c1.moveToNext()) {


                    t1=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                    t1.setText("textbox");
                    t1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff009999"));
                    l1.addView(t1);


                args[0] = Integer.toString((c1.getInt(acc_no_transCol)));
                args[1] = c1.getString(trans_typeCol);
                args[2] = Float.toString((c1.getFloat(amountCol)));

                t1.append("\nAccount Number: "+ args[0]+"\nTransaction Type: "+args[1]+"\nCurrent Balance: "+args[2]+"\n");
            //advance to the next record (first rec. if necessary)
            }

     }  



     catch (Exception e)
     {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }

    /* home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AccountTrackerActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
            }
     });*/
     }







}
```

Comment: There is a little check mark next to answer, underneath the vote tally. Just click it and you've accepted the answer.